# Performing different tasks for different data items in OpenCL?

Tags: performance, opencl

In summary, I'm looking for ways to deal with a situation where the very first step in the calculation is a conditional branch between two computationally expensive branches.

I'm essentially trying to implement a graphics filter that operates on an image and a mask - the mask is a bitmap array the same size as the image, and the filter performs different operations according to the value of the mask. So I basically want to do something like this for each pixel:

```
if(mask == 1) {
    foo();
} else {
    bar();
}
```

where both `foo` and `bar` are fairly expensive operations. As I understand it, when I run this code on the GPU it will have to calculate both branches for every pixel. (This gets even more expensive if there are more than two possible values for the mask.) Is there any way to avoid this?

One option I can think of would be to, in the host code, sort all the pixels into two 1-dimensional arrays based on the value of the mask at that point, and then entirely different kernels on them; then reconstruct the image from the two datasets afterwards. The problem with this is that, in my case, I want to run the filter iteratively, and both the image and the mask change with each iteration (the mask is actually calculated from the image). If I'm splitting the image into two buckets in the host code, I have to transfer each iteration of the image and mask from the GPU, and then the new buckets back to the GPU, introducing a new bottleneck to replace the old one.

Is there any other way to avoid this bottleneck?

Comment: (Note to diligent duplicate-hunters: there are several questions about avoiding divergence in OpenCL on this site already. None that I can find have answers that seem relevant to this one. So I've tried to present a fairly specific, distinct case in this question, that might hopefully have a fairly specific answer.)

Comment: By chance, do you know the statistical distribution of `mask`?

Comment: @ParkYoung-Bae, in my specific case the distribution is uneven - one value is going to be significantly more likely than the other, but both can be found scattered all over the image. Does that help? (If the distribution were something else, would you propose a different solution?)

Comment: It won't run both branches for every pixel; however, it will run both branches for every pixel if the warp or wavefront has pixels from both sets. If they are all inside or outside the mask then only that path runs. So depending on how solid the mask is, you might be fine. For example, if the mask was a circle then only the blocks on the edges would run both paths; the solid inside and solid outside areas would only run a single path. If the mask, on the other hand, is random, then both paths would run most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach might be to do a simple bucket sort within each work-group using the mask.

So add a local memory array and atomic counter for each value of mask. First read a pixel (or set of pixels might be better) for each work item, increment the appropriate atomic count and write the pixel address into that location in the array.

Then perform a work-group barrier.

Then as a final stage assign some set of work-items, maybe a multiple of the underlying vector size, to each of those arrays and iterate through it. Your operations will then be largely efficient, barring some loss at the ends, and if you look at enough pixels per work-item you may have very little loss of efficiency even if you assign the entire group to one mask value and then the other in turn.

Given that your description only has two values of the mask, fitting two arrays into local memory should be pretty simple and scale well.

Answer (score 0):

Push demanding task of a thread to shared/local memory(synchronization slows the process) and execute light ones untill all light ones finish(so the slow sync latency is hidden by this), then execute heavier ones.

```
if(mask == 1) {
    uploadFoo();//heavy, upload to __local object[]
} else {
    processBar(); // compute until, then check for a foo() in local memory if any exists.
    downloadFoo();
}
```

using a producer - consumer approach maybe.